What happens to ghcr packages if you delete the repo that owns them?
We have a repository (oldrepo) that was configured to have ghcr enabled and had automation pushing docker images to it (ghcr.io/ourorg/product-name).
The oldrepo repository has now been merged to our monorepo (newrepo), and we've archived oldrepo. If we browse to the ourorg/product-name ghcr package repository, it says at the top:

This repository has been archived by the owner on Aug 19, 2024. It is now read-only.

We have continued to be able to publish to the ourorg/product-name ghcr namespace from the monorepo, despite it saying the repository is read-only, but I'm unclear what happens if we were to finally delete the oldrepo repository entirely.
If I go into the ghcr repo's package settings, it shows ownership by oldrepo still, and says that "has been identified as the source for this package". It appears that I can delete this association (there's a trash can icon), but there's no way to manually add the correct newrepo.
We have updated our docker publishing to set org.opencontainers.image.source annotation to the new location, hoping this would update the repo for us, but it still seems to be clinging to oldrepo as the owner.
If I delete the old association with the trash icon, will it pick up the new org.opencontainers.image.source annotation from a recent push and move it over? Or if I delete it, will it offer me to assign a repo to it?
What happens if we delete the old repo entirely, will GitHub see that it no longer exists and point to the new source? Or will I just orphan everything?
